# How to create a datepicker inside the input field without the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

How do i create datepicker which can be inside an input field & workable like changing the dates & year. I want to create something similar to below image, the link as been provided.

I do not want to create a popup or drodown datepicker like the jquery calender. And also how do i insert this into the minimal form from the codedrops. http://tympanus.net/Development/MinimalForm/

Check the image in the below link.
http://awesomescreenshot.com/00f4n5pud0

Comment: @Michael Dibbets: Hi,
I've tried date pickers but those pops out. 
What I really want is the month and the year inside the input field and it should be able to select the periods just as the normal calender.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?

Comment: Post code of what you have tried so far. Right now it just looks like, hey I want this feature, write it for me.

Comment: Thanks man. Its time late. Issues sorted out Alhamdhulillah :)